# Sending data directly to Google Analytics using Java

Tags: java, spring, google-analytics

Is it possible to put google analytics in java? It means, I want to send all page view stats to google in backEnd side of my spring project
How this can be achieved? Libraries or official java api?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en

Comment: This is the library with example
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analytics/v3

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to generate this code from google analytics and paste it on all the sheets of your application. However if you have a layout it is much easier because you just have to put it there.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async th:src="@{https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-1XXXXXXX-1}" ></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

It worked for me!

Comment: This does not answer the question as it's related to the template and not in Java